# How do I combine all my localization satellite assembies into the EXE?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, embedded-resource

I've started adding multiple languages to my project using resx files (eg. MyText.resx, MyText.ru-RU.resx, etc.).

When I compile, I end up with files like this:

MyApp.exe
ru-RU\MyApp.resources.dll
es-ES\MyApp.resources.dll

Is there any easy way I can have everything compiled into the EXE? It's just a small utility which I distribute in a zip file, and it was nice that it didn't have tons of associated files!

I've been reading about the AssemblyLinker, but I'm not sure it does what I want. The EXE needs to behave as if those folders were there, and load the correct localisations for the users language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "[Netz](http://madebits.com/netz)" to re-pack your Assemblies after compilation. [They state in their helpfile](http://madebits.com/netz/help.php#res) that localized satellite assemblies are working seamlessly with .Net 1.1 and there is a workaround for later versions.

Comment: I eventually decided just to ship it as-is to avoid the hassle. The users don't seem to mind having all these random folders even when they're using it in English. They can always delete them with no ill-effects :)